# Is there a way to use IReadOnlyCollection<T>/IReadOnlyList<T> with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I gather that when working with collections protobuf-net needs `GetEnumerator` for serialization and a type with `Add` for the deserialization.

For types that don't have an `Add` you can set an inheriting type that does before deserialization. This works for example with `IEnumerable` and a `List`:

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Sheep
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Children { get; set; }
    public Sheep()
    {
        Children = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

```
var dolly = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.DeepClone(new Sheep
{
    Children = new[]
    {
        "Bonnie",
        "Sally",
        "Rosie",
        "Lucy",
        "Darcy",
        "Cotton"
    }
});
```

However, when I do the same with `IReadOnlyCollection` (or `IReadOnlyList`):

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Sheep
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Children { get; set; }
    public Sheep()
    {
        Children = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

> Unable to resolve a suitable Add method for System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

So, is there a way to make protobuf-net handle members of `IReadOnlyCollection`/`IReadOnlyList`?

---

EDIT: I've opened an issue for this feature on the project's repository: [Support IReadOnlyCollection/IReadOnlyList members](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/90)

Comment: Which protobuf library are you using? The one by marc?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, protobuf-net. Skeet's is  
protobuf-csharp-port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is "merge". For non-merge (or basically: with list replacement enabled), we could probably hard-code a concrete type and strategy, however, there is no obvious thing to do for merge otherwise.

There is no magic for this scenario at the moment; any solution would require library changes.

Comment: By "merge" do you mean adding to an existing collection? If so isn't it the same issue with `IEnumerable`, where it does work when you set a `List` before deserialization?

Comment: @i3arnon which is why it demands an Add method; in that scenario, it just calls Add - not an option here

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the difference between the two cases, as in both the `Add` is performed on the `List`.

Comment: @i3arnon indeed, but that is implemented as a specific hard-coded scenario (and List-T provides Add); no such special case currently exists for this case, and even if it did, it would be more complex (no Add)