# How to Serialize a Collection of Interface Objects Using Protobuf-Net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have the following class definitions:

```
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Foo))]
public interface IFoo
{
    double Bar { get; }
}



[ProtoContract]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private double _bar
    {
        get { return Bar / 10; }
        set { Bar = 10 * value; }
    }

    public double Bar { get; private set; }
}



[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
    public IReadOnlyList<IFoo> Foos { get; private set; }
}
```

When I try to serialize a *MyClass* object using protobuf-net, I get the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : It was not possible to prepare a serializer for: MyNamespace.MyClass
>   ----> System.InvalidOperationException : No serializer defined for type: MyNamespace.IFoo

In my case, I know that the concrete type of the items stored in *MyClass.Foos* is *Foo*.  How can I tell protobuf to use type *Foo* anywhere it sees type *IFoo*?  Alternatively, how can I make it include *Foo* as one of the classes available to implement *IFoo* in the collection?

**-- EDIT --**

The answer from Sam is close enough such that it revealed another issue with this approach.  Namely, that [it is not possible to serialize a property of type IReadOnlyList<T> using protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557636/is-there-a-way-to-use-ireadonlycollectiont-ireadonlylistt-with-protobuf-net).  There is a simple workaround, however, since the list is being created in the constructor of MyClass.  Hence, MyClass can change to the following:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
    private List<IFoo> MutableFoos { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<IFoo> Foos
    {
        get { return MutableFoos; }
    }
}
```

However, serialization of *MyClass* is still failing with the message, "*System.InvalidOperationException : No suitable conversion operator found for surrogate: MyNamespace.IFoo / MyNamespace.Foo*".

Comment: Sam removed his answer (it didn't compile), but since I edited my question due to his response, I felt it may be useful to summarize his solution to give context to the edit.  Essentially, what he suggested, was to use a surrogate, via a call to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IFoo), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(Foo))` in the static constructor of MyClass.

Comment: I've just hit the same issue with the surrogate InvalidOperationException - did you ever solve it?

Comment: @kirbatious Usually I'll answer my own question if I figure something out, so my guess is no.  However, I'll double check the code in the next few days to see if I ultimately figured out how to make this work.  I'll either post an answer, or replace this comment once I know for certain.

Comment: @kirbatious Unfortunately, I eventually gave up on this.  Since I only had one implementing type for `IFoo`, I just made the private serialized member use the underlying concrete class.  I have added an answer explaining how that works in my case.  However, I *think* you might be able to do something like this using Surrogates, if you serialize the concrete class name with each member of the list (or the containing class, if you know everything in the list has the same type).  I have never tried that, though.

Comment: I have gotten this to work. The main difference I can tell from your original question and what I've been able to implement is I put `ProtoContract` and `ProtoMember` on the interface. But my implementation is rather complex using an interface, then a generic abstract class, then concrete classes implementing the generic abstract class. I rigged up the interface with ProtoBuf decorators, ProtoInclude the concrete classes, and decorated the concrete classes with ProtoMember where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I was never able to get this working where the interface class was used in the serialized member.  Instead, I ended up having to put the concrete class as the list member type.  The following is what ultimately worked for me:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
    private List<Foo> MutableFoos { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<IFoo> Foos
    {
        get { return MutableFoos; }
    }
}
```

Note the type in the serialized member is `List<Foo>`, instead of `List<IFoo>`.  I never figured out how to get the latter to work.